# ZF + PHPUnit: How to assert existence of html elements within ajax response?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

Should I extend the ControllerTestCase and create a custom method to handle this?  What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX response should be no different than any other response. So no subclassing should be necessary.

But if you mean "how to test that the response AJAX request generated from the file I'm testing is correct?" there is no way to do that (except Selenium tests maybe). And it's not PHP's job to test this - you should use JavaScript tests to test it.

When you're sure the AJAX is calling correct URL with correct params, you can create the AJAX request artificaly and test the response as normal request.